# How to Factory reset Elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno, system

i want to factory reset elementary os system. How to make it? please help me

Comment: So do you want to completely reinstall the system, wiping out all your data? Or reinstall the OS files, but keep your data? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean *exactly* by factory reset (see SilverWolf's comment), but there is a button in Settings > About system, that is called "Reset to factory settings" (or similar, I use Czech locale).